# What is the lowest speed recorded of an electron moving in a vacuum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, electrons

What are some experiments that tried to slow free electrons down instead of accelerating them? Can you run a linear particle accelerator backwards? What happens when an electron reaches zero velocity?

Comment: Single electrons have been placed in Penning traps.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. Why do you think something interesting happens when an electron 'reaches' zero velocity? (Keeping in mind that free electrons not necessarily need to be 'slowed down' to be slow, they just can arise with basically zero kinetic energy, for example by ionizing an atom with a photon that has barely enough energy for ionization.)

Comment: Whenever a [space charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_charge) develops in a vacuum tube there's essentially a cloud of stationary (or very slow moving) free electrons causing it.

Answer (score 7):

The [KATRIN experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KATRIN) (and other similar experiments before it) use huge MAC-E filters to slow down electrons that are emitted from a beta source (tritium in the case of KATRIN). These electrons are slowed down using a precisely-controlled retarding potential to a precision of sub-electronvolts. Though of course, nothing special happens when electrons are slowed down to a standstill, why would there.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this "Though of course, nothing special happens when electrons are slowed down to a standstill, why would there."? I believe no one has ever seen an electron to be stationary experimentally.

Comment: What is there to elaborate? Nobody has ever seen a black cat in a completely dark room, and yet, why would you expect anything special to happen if you put a black cat into a completely dark room?

Comment: I believe it is worth mentioning, that electrons are quantum mechanical entities, subject to the HUP.

Comment: I was thinking about the wave-particle nature of matter. It is well known that the higher the frequency the more the photon acts like a particle ( it becomes more localized) I was wondering if the reverse can happen to an electron. A standing electron should have an infinite wavelength and while I know that cannot be achieved . I think that getting close to it would make it easier to study uncertainty. You know, by detecting charge and stuff like that we could trace the path of a wave-particle.

Answer (score 6):

An electron with zero velocity is just a stationary electron - its properties do not change. Milikan’s [oil drop experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_drop_experiment), designed to measure the charge on the electron, basically slows down electrons until they are almost stationary.

Comment: Oil drop experiment was far from getting a slow _free_ electron. Instead it slowed down a "car" that an electron was sitting in (the drop). The electron itself could have a large $\langle |\vec v|\rangle$ being in a bound orbital.

Answer (score 2):

[Trapping electrons in a room-temperature microwave Paul trap](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.06681)

[News Article](https://physics.aps.org/articles/v14/16)

In the linked UC Berkeley experiment cold electrons are trapped in a Paul trap and detected up to a second later.